# C++ Using a function to return a new matrix

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

For my hw I was to create a new matrix C from 2 given matrices (A and B, both N rows x M columns) based on the following:

```
C(row,col) = max{A(row,col),B(row,col)} if row + col < (M+N)/2 

C(row,col) = min{A(row,col),B(row,col)} if row + col >= (M+N)/2
```

I am to assume that A,B,N,M are passed to my function as parameters, while I can pass other parameters as well.

Here is what I have

```
void minMax(int A[N][M], int B[N][M], int C[N][M])
{
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
        {
            if(i+j < (M+N)/2)
            {
                C[i][j] = A[i][j] > B[i][j] ? A[i][j] : B[i][j];
            }
            else
            {
                C[i][j] = A[i][j] < B[i][j] ? A[i][j] : B[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this correct? I am also asked how I will "return" C. Am I doing that with this function already since I'm filling up C?

Comment: what is this "if(i+j < (M+N)/2)" for  ?  Aren't you accomplishing what you want without it?

Comment: The function doesn't actually return anything, but it *initializes* the `C` matrix. And no, the values of `N` and `M` is *not* passed in as arguments, either you need to have it as global constants or preprocessor macros.

Comment: also pass in by reference, use pointers

Comment: ok... the do what you say "if row + col = (M+N)/2", why condition with "<" sign

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you have changed the original conditions. i guess you must undo the edit.

Comment: Your description is incomplete. It says what to do `if row + col = (M+N)/2` but not what to do otherwise.

Comment: Some edited it. I'm not sure why. It's supposed to be

C(row,col) = max{A(row,col),B(row,col)} if row + col < (M+N)/2

C(row,col) = min{A(row,col),B(row,col)} if row + col >= (M+N)/2

Comment: I see. In that case it looks okay. And, yes, C is filled by your routine so there is nothing more to "return".

Comment: @ooga Thanks for your response. Why are others saying that this just initializes C then? And supposedly my N  and M are not being passed as parameters

Comment: The term "initialize" is not technically correct here. You are assigning values to the elements. That's it. As for N and M, I assumed that they were defined constants. If not, then you'll have to pass them, and since you've labelled this as C++, you're not supposed to use variable-length arrays. Perhaps a std::vector instead.

Comment: @ooga I set N and M and const int. That should be fine then right? Thanks again for your response and help!